# How do I select a specific cell in a specific row in a Tabulator table

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I want to be able to programmatically select or grab a specific cell in a specific row - for example to get the 7th column of the row with data.id = 1:

```
tableObject.selectRow(1).getCell(6)
```

I've been playing for ages with  this and I can't get it to work. Help please.

Comment: Would be helpful to provide the HTML to test the code on.

Answer (score -1):

After much fiddling, I've discovered the solution:

```
tableObject.getRowFromPosition(0).getCell('fieldname')
```